# Why replacing colors process in numpy array never ends

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing

I am reading a .gif image using the imageio library in Python (which reads the .gif format as a list of frames, each are numpy arrays). I want to replace all the RGB colors in the .gif image with a certain fixed color (to possibly use an if statement later to change some parts of the image).

The data are on the form of something like `[[23 234 23 24], [34, 46, 57 255]]`...

This is my code:

```
gifimage = imageio.mimread(inputgif)
for x in range(len(gifimage)):
  shape = gifimage[x].shape
  for l in range(0, shape[0]):
    for y in range(0, shape[1]):
      gifimage[x][l][y] = [50, 205, 50, 255] #255 is just the alpha channel which I can ignore.
```

Also tried:

```
for x in range(len(gifimage)):
  shape = gifimage[x].shape
  for l in range(0, shape[0]):
    for y in range(0, shape[1]):
      gifimage[x][l][y][0] = 50
      gifimage[x][l][y][1] = 205
      gifimage[x][l][y][2] = 50
      gifimage[x][l][y][2] = 255
```

But when I run it, it never ends. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing you can eliminate some for loops. If you just want to reassign all of the pixels to a single color you can do the following:

```
gifimage[:][:][:] = [50, 205, 50, 255]
```

Just to be sure I follow, this will change **every** pixel to lime green.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. Now I can play with it by if statements to replace only the ones I desire.

Comment: But I am also curious to know why my for loops didn't work?